# Как получить экземляр сервиса?

Tags: symfony3

У меня есть команда унаследованная от `ContainerAwareCommand`. В методе `execute` я инициализирую переменную.
Команду запускаю через консоль, а потом, в контроллере, пытаюсь получить ее экземпляр. В итоге переменная, которая была инициализирована `execute` у меня `null`.

Сервис регистрировал так:

```
services:
  server_command:
    class: AppBundle\ServerCommand
    calls:
      - [setContainer,['@service_container']]
```

Сервис-команда описывается следующим образом:

```
class ServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    private $server;

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('srv:run');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln([
            'Server started'
        ]);

        $this->server = new Server();
        $this->server->setContainer($this->getContainer());        
        $this->server->run();
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        $this->server->foo();
    }
}
```

Экземпляр пытаюсь получить так:

```
$serverCommand = $this->get('server_command');
$serverCommand->foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$application = new Application('echo', '1.0.0');

$command = $application->find('srv:run');

$arguments = [
    'name' => 'Fabien',
];

$input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
$output = new BufferedOutput();

$returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);
```

Comment: А это не запускает новый экземпляр? Просто, этот сервис должен работать постоянно. Получается, что для того, чтобы запустить его, мне нужно дергать метод в контроллере, что не очень хорошо.

Comment: Приведенный пример не обязан выполняться в контроллере. Получение экземпляра команды в первых двух строках кода. Остальная часть кода содержит пример запуска команды.

Answer (score 0):

Нет-нет-нет и еще раз нет. Не надо так проектировать свое приложение.

- Никогда не запускайте команды в контроллерах (какой бы хорошей идеей это не казалось), команда должна запускать какой-то сервис(ы)
- Вы запускаете в консоли команду, а потом ожидаете получить переменную где-то в каком-то контроллере - нет. Команда запустилась, отработала и завершила свое выполнение. И все.

Рассказывайте чего хотите добиться или никто вам в этом не поможет.

(хотя спустя 8 месяцев вопрос исчерпал себя сам :))